# How do you wire up the PCA9600 I2C bus extender to use differential signalling at 12V?

Tags: i2c, differential, buffer, serial-bus

I would like to use a 12V differential signal between two NXP [PCA9600](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9600.pdf) I2C buffers to extend I2C at 100kHz to about 15m over 100-ohm twisted pair (CAT6).  My original understanding from a brief look at the pinout/block diagram is that I can use a twisted pair for each TX/RX pair that provides each SDA/SCL line:

[image: PCA9600 pair]

There is only one input voltage (Vcc) and it is (appears to be) used for both the master side of the bus and the TX/RX pair for each of the SDA/SCL lines.  Looking through the datasheet on how to make the TX/RX lines run at 12V, I found this on page 12, which appears to represent what I'm looking for:

[image: PCA9600 long distance]

**My *actual* question is this:**

- How do I wire up the PCA9600 to a 3.3v I2C bus with a 12V differential signal to the remote PCA9600?

**However,** this datasheet has brought up a few other questions along the way:

1. Why are TX and RX tied together above in Figure 13?  Doesn't that defeat the point of differential, or is this just notation, and I am supposed to understand that the TX/RX lines are actually on separate wires (in the same twisted pair) with each wire pulled up to 12v?
2. Figure 13 above shows 12V going *into* the PCA9600, but there is only a single input voltage (Vcc) on the chip's pinout shown below.  Does the 12V line simply pull up the differential lines, *or does 12V actually connect to a pin*?

   [image: PCA9600 pinout]
3. Should Vcc be the bus voltage of 3.3v as I suspect, or is it really 12V?  (If it is 12V, what protects the master side of the bus from 12 volts?)
4. Assuming the 12V line is simply a pull-up on the differential line, what should the resistor value be?

   - The datasheet (page 7) says TX and TY pins have a max load current of 30mA, so a 400-ohm pull-up to 12v gets us there...but a 400-ohm pull-up into the 100-ohm balanced feedline (twisted pair) would cause a 4:1 VSWR, a rather poor mismatch.  Is this really correct?

Comment: Well, the chip does not have differential signals, so there is no answer how to wire it. Is that an acceptable answer?

Comment: The only occurrence of "differential" in the PCA9600 datasheet is _Simple conversion of I2C-bus SDA or SCL signals to multi-drop differential bus hardware, for example, via compatible PCA82C250_. I.e. you need additional devices to get differential I2C.

Comment: A quick search found [Differential I2C Long Cable Extender PCA9600 Module](https://sandboxelectronics.com/?p=3988) which uses the PCA9600 and PCA82C251T CAN transeiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chip does not use or support differential signaling. So this chip may not do what you expect it to do. It does not have differential drivers, it has separate TX output and RX input on the bus cable side. If differential bus is requied then this chip can drive TX and RX of a differential PHY.

It can simply be used to boost the voltage up to 15V on the cable side.

There's many diagrams how to connect it in the data sheet. See figures 11, 13, 18, and Table 7 for component values when e.g. you have 5V MCUs and 12V I2C bus cable.

Comment: Hmm, ok maybe I misunderstood what the device was to begin with.  Can you answer item #1 _"Why are TX and RX tied together above in Figure 13?"_    Are they really connected electrically, or is it just showing they are bundled in the same pair?

Comment: The TX and RX are externally tied together electrically for a single-ended cable interface. Fig 13 clearly shows 12V supply paired with 12V single-ended SDA, and ground paired with 12V single-ended SCL.

Comment: So what is the point of separating TX and RX onto their own pins if they just get tied together externally?

Comment: @KJ7LNW Like said in the data sheet, it allows you to connect some bi-directional differential PHY which has separate TX and RX pins, or bi-directional galvanic isolation with separate TX and RX optocouplers like in fig 12.

Comment: Thanks for the extra set of eyes on the datasheet.  I was really stuck on why TX/RX were externally tied and I appreciate you clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

As @Justme noted above, additional components are needed to get differential signaling and would require 4 pairs:

[image: PCA9600 Differential Schematic]

More info here, using the [26LS31](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26ls31m.pdf) for differential signaling:

- http://ds.theatr.us/Long%20distance%20I2C%20buffer.pdf

See also, the comment from @ChesterGillon which only needs 3 pairs:

- "*A quick search found [Differential I2C Long Cable Extender PCA9600 Module](https://sandboxelectronics.com/?p=3988) which uses the PCA9600 and PCA82C251T CAN transeiver."*
- [PCA9600 Differential I2C Long Cable Extender with Boost Convertor (product link)](https://sandboxelectronics.com/?product=pca9600-differential-i2c-long-cable-extender-with-boost-convertor-2)